# MySQL Update only certain fields in a table

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have some insurance information in a website, and I'd like to only edit certain fields the user wants to change like for example:
user, id, phone, address, city

and the user wants to change his city and phone...do i have to make a query for each specific case or is there a code that can help me retrieve the key(phone) and value (9397171602)??

to then send it in a query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are number of ways to update a record safely. Conside the following pseudo code + php program.

```
class Example
{
   function UpdateRecord($editedRecord)
    {
        //Fetch existing record from the database
        $originalRecord=DB::fetchExample($editedRecord->getId()) 
        //validate each edited field and it is valid then assign its value
        //to the originalRecord's field

        if(IsValid($editedRecord->getName())
          {
            $originalRecord->setName($editedRecord->getName());
          }
        .....

        //update the record.
        $originalRecord->Update(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Basic update would take the form of:

```
UPDATE table_name SET column_1 = value_1, column_2 = value_2 WHERE column_3 = value_3
```

Where col1, col2 would be your city and phone, and col3 would be the user id. Check out the MySQL website http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html for more info

Comment: Yeah, but in that table I actually have 9 columns...if I do just one query for every situation that may arise ...for example UPDATE table_name SET column_1 = value_1, column_2 = value_2 WHERE column_3 = value_3

Comment: @neurotikYeah, but in that table I actually have 9 columns...if I do just one query for every situation that may arise ...for example UPDATE table_name SET column_1 = value_1, column_2 = value_2 column_3 = value_3.........untill 9WHERE column_3 = value_3 –

If there are unfilled blanks in the form, will it affect the table? As in, erase prior information?

Comment: @Skynight - Use JavaScript/JQuery at client side validation and write PHP methods which validate user input.

Comment: @Skynight - Sorry, I don't understand your question... What do you mean by "if I do just one query for every situation that may arise"?

Comment: @Skynight - Yes it will affect the table, and yes it will erase any prior information, as long as the conditions after the WHERE statement are satisfied. Any additional checks for validity should be done before issuing this statement.

Comment: @Skynight - If you mean a separate query for changing each of the fields (city and phone) that you mentioned, then no, you can do it in one query.

Answer (score 1):

Just add some sql to it:

```
$sql = "UPDATE example SET col_1 = val_1, col_9 = val_9 WHERE col_7 = val_7";
mysql_query($sql);
```

Then replace the columns and values with you stuff. For further info: [PHP MySql Update](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp)